# Expanding/collapsing table rows while the text shortens/lengthens

Tags: javascript

I have, for example, 3 rows from a table. Each of the rows gets its content from a database. By default when the row is collapsed, the text should be shortened -

```
trs[i].innerText = trs[i].innerText.substring(0,25) + '...';
```

When a user clicks on the div it expands, and if clicked again - collapses.

```
if(tr.style.height == "150px")
        {
             tr.style.height = "20px";
        }
    else {
        tr.style.height = "150px";
    }
```

So far, so good, but I want the text to be shortened only if the div is collapsed. With my solution when the page loads the text is shortened, but when the row is expanded it remains shortened. How can I fix this? I can only think of when the row expands  to call an AJAX function which returns the original data, but I don't think it's the best possible way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you'd have to store the full text before shortening it.

```
trs[i].fullText = trs[i].innerText;
trs[i].innerText = trs[i].innerText.substring(0,25) + '...';
```

Then you can restore it in the handler:

```
tr.innerText = tr.fullText;
tr.style.height = "150px";
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XKyah/). I'm using jQuery to select the elements, but you already have the correct tr's anyway. If you were using jQuery you could also use `$(tr).data("fullText", $(tr).text())` which avoids some minor memory leaks with adding properties to DOM elements in old versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: I don't think it can be done by storing the full text, because the text is shortened when the page loads and the expand occurs when an user clicks.

Comment: @user1163870 Can you give some more detail on what problem you see? It works fine in the fiddle.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/f/827/snapwo.png/

The rows are collapsed and the text is shortened by default. When a user clicks on some row, both the row and the text should expand. I'm sorry for not explaining it very well previously.
edit: by default i mean on page load

Comment: edit2: I still haven't explained the problem. I apologize, I have a lot on my mind. So the problem is: okay, this works for a single div(tr). But when it comes to 2000 rows from the database..?

Comment: @user1163870 Well, you are truncating the strings on the client so they have already been sent there in full. Storing them in memory shouldn't be a problem unless they are really really long. I can see that there might be some problems with the initial download size, but the question doesn't suggest that this is a concern at the moment and that only changes on the client side code are required. What specifically are you concerned about?